# IE Almost Standards mode, how do I know when I am in it

Tags: internet-explorer-9, compatibility-mode

According to the MS flowchart ... there is a mode called 'almost standards'.  http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_1.svg

I THINK my page is landing in it but the developer panel tells me it is in IE9 Standards for document mode.

Additionally,  I don't even see an option for ALMOST standards in the dev panel.

So how do I know that I am in it for sure?  I am assuming that I am because of the flowchart and that the document mode that says 'IE9 Standards' is just the best they can do ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't want to be in any transitional mode which implements some old features, and some nearly-modern features. You will be in one of those modes if you provide a doctype that explicit opts you in (see your linked resource for those particular doctypes). When no valid doctype is provided, you will be in Quirks Mode.

To ensure that you're in standards mode, use the following doctype on the first line of your document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You'll also find that many people will instruct IE to implement "edge," meaning it ought to implement its latest feature-set (which is what it does already when in standards mode).

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Ya, I DONT want to be in it... we are just having some weird issues with DevEx and the META tag.  Where certain newer things work with just the META tag but their dropdowns do not but when we add the HEADER instead of the META tag, the dropdowns do work.  Its crazy!  We dont want the HEADER option because we dont want one version across the whole app, we just want this one page to have the newest version.

Comment: Jonathan, you should read through the flowchart I provided above.  It makes things a lot more understandable (except for the ALMOST standards part :-)  ).  But as it shows META takes precedence over DOCTYPE... unless of course you have an iFrame.

Comment: @toddv I'm aware that the meta tag (or response header) is more authoritative than the doctype, but what I was pointing out is that you don't need to set IE=edge when you have a standards-inducing doctype.

Comment: @toddv I believe you will be in *almost standards* if you use a Transitional doctype. Just use the standard `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype and you'll safely find yourself in Standards Mode.